# Why won't the padding go away?

Tags: css

I have been really stumped on coding this mybb theme.  So first off there seems to be a constant padding around the entire container.  With firefox I used the identify and the container is only reading my screen to be like 1583 wide while my screen in actuality is 1,600. It has padding for the height as well.  Also it seems that whenever I adjust the width to a smaller width it is weighted to the left.  I don't want everything floating to the left.

http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/4378/3xeu.png

In this photo provided I have all container, and body set to 100% width.  The menu seems to go past it only because I said the width of that to 9,000px wide.  But it refuses to go any more left.

Answer (score 1):

it's a `margin`, not a `padding`, it's set in some browsers by default in the body tag, just add this to your CSS:

```
body{margin:0}
```

Comment: consider up-voting this answer and mark it as "Solution" to your problem

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer above, you should really considering using and adding normalize.css with all your projects/code in order to avoid these issues in the future.

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/